# What is Mr. Data's full name?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

What is the full official name Doctor Noonien Soong gave to his android (known in ST: TNG as "Data")?

Is the entire name simply Data, or is it an acronym?

Comment: I would *guess* that is Data's name in its entirety, considering the other androids he built that weren't meant to actually pass for human (B4 and Lore).

Comment: There are only two possible options, either it is Data or it is Data Soong

Comment: It's worth noting that not all cultures use multiple names today.

Comment: Data discussed the meaning of his name early in the series, possibly in "Encounter at Farpoint". I vaguely recall that he implied that he had chosen the name himself, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @user11295 really? I would have thought Soong could have named his androids like cats if he wanted. Data’s full name could be Mr Data Bigglesworth Fluffypants III.

Comment: @bitmask: I dom’t blame him; [the word comes from the Czech word *robota*, meaning ‘forced labour’](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=robot%20etymology).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Interesting. That is a factoid I will use excruciatingly. Thank you :)

Comment: If his name were Data Soong, then Picard et al. would call him Mr. Soong, not Mr. Data. So it's clear that Data is his surname.

Comment: @KefSchecter: why are you so [racist against Bajorans????](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Bajoran#Names)

Comment: Surely if his name were "Data Soong", Soong would be the surname (inherited from Noonien Soong), not the given name.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

In the second season episode "The Measure of a Man", Riker pulls up [Data's schematics](http://images.wikia.com/memoryalpha/en/images/c/c3/Data_schematics_1.jpg) on a wall monitor.  On the lower right of the display, we see "LT CDR NFN/NMI DATA" which should be read as "Lieutenant Commander No First Name No Middle Initial Data."

[image]

This was [confirmed by illustrator Rick Sternbach during the "Next Generation Slide Show" panel at Baycon 1989](http://stng.36el.com/st-tng/trivia/convention_notes.html).

> Also from Measure Of A Man, this is Data's full name as shown by the
>   Enterprise computer (to Cmdr. Riker): Lt. Cmdr. NFN NMI Data. Spelled
>   out, this becomes: Lieutenant Commander "No First Name" "No Middle
>   Initial" Data.

Comment: That notation assumes that FirstName MiddleInitial LastName is the normal pattern for personal names. That's not even valid for 20th- or 21st-century Earth humans; it's far less likely apply to most Starfleet personnel. So it's probably a bit unrealistic -- but it does get the idea across.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I guess the fact that their personnel DB still requires First/Middle/Last means that COBOL will be alive and well in the 24th century. :)

Comment: @mricon: That would explain why we haven't seen time travelers from the 101st century or later; civilization fell due to the Y10K problem.

Comment: Is there any canonical backup of that full form?

Comment: @Sachin The abbreviation are in use in the real world on forms and such.  There's not likely to be any canon reference to something this minor.

Comment: @SachinShekhar and KyleJones:  TNG 5x03, [Ensign Ro](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ensign_Ro_(episode)).  The new character, Ro Laren, gets a little peeved when she's called "Ensign Laren" instead of "Ensign Ro", as Bajoran surnames come first - implying that FirstName LastName is most common in the Federation.

Comment: @Izkata The irony being that there are cultures here on Earth where FamilyName GivenName is the norm.

Comment: @JAB Oh, [it goes far beyond that here on Earth](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).  Also I regret using "first" and "last" in my earlier comment.

Comment: In addition to NFN and NMI, there is a common modern-day initialism "MIO" for "Middle Initial Only". It is used in some official documents for people whose middle names consist only of an initial. This was the case with Harry S. (MIO) Truman". His middle name was not Simon, Simpson, Samuel, or Stephen, it was S. Literally.

Comment: @JAB: It's not about whether it occurs on Earth, it's about First-Middle-Last being the most _common_. Even if not the most common on Earth, it was at least the most common in the cultural region for the developers of the data system. Just because Earth uses two standards doesn't mean that every Earth system inherently uses both standards at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to remove the direct quote and leave your own commentary. If anything, you'd want it the other way around since if the link dies, your own commentary is of a lower value.

Comment: @Valorum Yeah, I screwed that up.  Rolled back.

Comment: @KeithThompson NMI/NFI is common even in today's military as a designation, as well as on government forms that require full legal names.

Comment: @Flater: "it's about First-Middle-Last being the most _common_. (...) Just because Earth uses two standards doesn't mean that every Earth system inherently uses both standards at the same time." - Earth doesn't use *two* standards, it rather uses a dozen or more. With that in mind, it seems like a good idea to not assume the presence of specific name components that only exist in one (or a few) of these standards.

Comment: NMI could also mean "Non-Maskable Interrupt" ;-)

Comment: Terminology: aren't _all_ 3-part names ‘first-middle-last’, by definition? AIUI, the issue is not whether the first name comes first and the last name last — they clearly do! — it's whether the first name is a given name and the last name a family name, or vice versa (or some other combination, such as all names being given names).

Answer (score 8):

According to [StarTrek.com database](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/data) his full name was simply Data.

I don't recall hearing or reading about the origin of the name but it always sounded right :)

Comment: The origin is obvious: Data's positronic brain contains oodles of data. :)

Answer (score -1):

Data was initially a nickname given to him by Starfleet personnel.  Data did not recall his life prior to being metaphysically born again by being turned on after a memory wipe.  Thus, to the OP's question, we don't know what Doctor Soong named him.  We can presume he was given a first name, because Lore had a first name.  It's a compelling thing to wonder if Data ever considered adopted the surname Soong in some fashion.

I appreciate the challenge below to back up my answer.  It would seem I was partially correct; Data chose his own name.

> EPISODE: Datalore S01E14
>
> TASHA: You were just lying out there in the open? No identity record,
>   no instructions?
>
> DATA: Only a layer of dust.
>
> RIKER: What's the first thing you remember, Data?
>
> DATA: Opening my eyes. Looking into the eyes of the Tripoli landing
>   party. They believed that the signal device sensed their presence and
>   activated me.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_(Star_Trek)

In the prologue to the novel adaptation for Encounter at Farpoint by David Gerrold, Data chose his own name, due to his love for, and identification with, knowledge.

Comment: Data appears to be the name that Dr Soong gave him